# Porting Xtext Eclipse project to Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, xtext

I am trying to port an existing Xtext 2.21.0 project from Eclipse 2020-03 to Maven.

I have generated an example Xtext Maven project using Eclipse, and then populated it with my DSL. The issue is that my grammars cannot find the references to other grammars.

```
529  ERROR XtextGeneratorLanguage - [XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:1 Couldn't resolve reference to Grammar 'abc.generator.ServiceGenerator'., XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:4 Couldn't resolve reference to EPackage 'http://www.generator.abc/ServiceGenerator'., XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:117 STRING cannot be resolved to a rule, XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:249 INT cannot be resolved to a rule, TransformationDiagnostic: null:248 Datatype rules may only use other datatype rules, lexer rules and keywords. (ErrorCode: InvalidDatatypeRule)]
531  ERROR Mwe2Launcher       - Problems running workflow abc.generator.GenerateRawNotificationGenerator: Problem parsing 'file:/C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/eclipse_plugin_pom/abc.generator/../abc.generator/src/abc/generator/VarDefinitionGenerator.xtext':
XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:1 Couldn't resolve reference to Grammar 'abc.generator.ServiceGenerator'.
XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:4 Couldn't resolve reference to EPackage 'http://www.generator.abc/ServiceGenerator'.
XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:117 STRING cannot be resolved to a rule
XtextLinkingDiagnostic: null:249 INT cannot be resolved to a rule
TransformationDiagnostic: null:248 Datatype rules may only use other datatype rules, lexer rules and keywords. (ErrorCode: InvalidDatatypeRule)
```

POM files are just the default generated POM by Eclipse Xtext 2.21.0, the only modification is my project names and URIs.

Mwe2 file:

```
module abc.generator.GenerateRawNotificationGenerator

import org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.*
import org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils.StandaloneSetup
import org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.model.project.*

var rootPath = ".."

Workflow {
    
    component = XtextGenerator 
    {
        configuration = 
        {
            project = StandardProjectConfig 
            {
                baseName = "abc.generator"
                rootPath = rootPath
                runtimeTest = 
                {
                    enabled = true
                }
                
                eclipsePlugin = 
                {
                    enabled = true
                }
                
                eclipsePluginTest = 
                {
                    enabled = true
                }
                
                createEclipseMetaData = true
            }
            code = 
            {
                encoding = "windows-1252"
                lineDelimiter = "\r\n"
                fileHeader = "/*\n * generated by Xtext \${version}\n */"
            }
        }
        
        language = StandardLanguage 
        {
            name = "abc.generator.ServiceGenerator"
            fileExtensions = "services"

            serializer = 
            {
                generateStub = false
            }
            
            validator = 
            {
                composedCheck = "org.eclipse.xtext.validation.NamesAreUniqueValidator"
            }
        }

        language = StandardLanguage 
        {
            name = "abc.generator.VarDefinitionGenerator"
            fileExtensions = "vardefinition"

            serializer = 
            {
                generateStub = false
            }
            
            validator = 
            {
                composedCheck = "org.eclipse.xtext.validation.NamesAreUniqueValidator"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ServiceGenerator header:

```
grammar abc.generator.ServiceGenerator with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals
generate serviceGenerator "http://www.generator.abc/ServiceGenerator"
import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore
```

VarDefinitionGenerator header:

```
grammar abc.generator.VarDefinitionGenerator with abc.generator.ServiceGenerator
generate varDefinitionGenerator "http://www.generator.abc/VarDefinitionGenerator"

import "http://www.generator.abc/ServiceGenerator"
import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore
```

I must mention I am not familiar at all with Xtext, but I am familiar with Maven.
This project is working just fine in Eclipse 2020-03, but we need to get rid of Eclipse because of its bugs. I tried upgrading to Eclipse 2023-09, Java 17 and Xtext 2.32.0, but then the project doesn't work (some Injected variables come back as null).

What I cannot understand is whether the Eclipse plugin.xml file should be added somewhere in the mwe2 file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<?eclipse version="3.0"?>
<plugin>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.generated_package">
        <package 
            uri = "http://www.generator.abc/ServiceGenerator"
            class = "abc.generator.serviceGenerator.ServiceGeneratorPackage"
            genModel = "model/generated/ServiceGenerator.genmodel" />
    </extension>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.generated_package">
        <package 
            uri = "http://www.generator.abc/VarDefinitionGenerator"
            class = "abc.generator.varDefinitionGenerator.VarDefinitionGeneratorPackage"
            genModel = "model/generated/VarDefinitionGenerator.genmodel" />
    </extension>
</plugin>
```

Comment: regarding inject == null: make sure you dont use annotation from the `javax.inject` repo.

Comment: @ChristianDietrich Yep, that was the issue, changed to import com.google.inject.Inject. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. It seems that there is a bug in xtext Maven which is solved by adding the `src` directory to `additionalClasspathElements`.

By doing this you do not need to define multiple `referencedResource` inside your `.mwe2` file anymore.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher</mainClass>
        ...

        <additionalClasspathElements>
            <additionalClasspathElement>${project.basedir}/src</additionalClasspathElement>
        </additionalClasspathElements>
    </configuration>
```

Many many thanks for the contribuitor of the solution here: https://github.com/eclipse/xtext/issues/2394#issuecomment-1511031257

I accidentally found it by first defining multiple `referencedResource` for each language in the `.mwe2` file, but this lead to another PDA error which led me to the proper solution for both issues.

Answer (score 0):

you can tell the 2nd language about the first

```
language = StandardLanguage {
    referencedResource="platform:/resource/<project>/src/<PathTo>/<ParentDsl>.xtext"
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work. It gives out the same error.

Comment: can you please provide a reproducer repo